# Linux PHP ExtractTo returns whole path instead of the file structure

Tags: php, linux

I am pulling my hair out over here. I have spent the last week trying to figure out why the ZipArchive extractTo method behaves differently on linux than on our test server (WAMP).

Below is the most basic example of the problem. I simply need to extract a zip that has the following structure:

```
my-zip-file.zip
-username01
    --filename01.txt
    -images.zip
        --image01.png
    -songs.zip
        --song01.wav
-username02
    --filename01.txt
    -images.zip
       --image01.png
    -songs.zip
       --song01.wav
```

The following code will extract the root zip file and keep the structure on my WAMP server. I do not need to worry about extracting the subfolders yet.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"])) {
$filename = $_FILES["zip_file"]["name"];
$source = $_FILES["zip_file"]["tmp_name"];
$errors = array();  

$name = explode(".", $filename);

$continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;
if(!$continue) {
    $errors[] = "The file you are trying to upload is not a .zip file. Please try again.";
}

$zip = new ZipArchive();

if($zip->open($source) === FALSE)
{
    $errors[]= "Failed to open zip file.";
}

if(empty($errors))
{
    $zip->extractTo("./uploads");
    $zip->close();
    $errors[] = "Zip file successfully extracted! <br />";
}

}
?>
```

The output from the script above on WAMP extracts it correctly (keeping the file structure).

When I run this on our live server the output looks like this:

```
--username01\filename01.txt
--username01\images.zip
--username01\songs.zip
--username02\filename01.txt
--username02\images.zip
--username02\songs.zip
```

I cannot figure out why it behaves differently on the live server. Any help will be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Hey @Zachary. It's not clear to me what exactly is the issue. Do you want to get in both systems the zip extracted recursively?

Comment: Thanks for responding! The issue is that linux destroys the file structure when I extract the zip file.....I believe it has something to do with the backslashes but I cant figure out how to make it use forward slashes to retain the directory structure

Comment: I think I got the problem: the slashes became part of the file name on Linux. Is it?

Comment: Correct...There needs to be a folder called username01 then inside that folder should be filename01.txt AND images.zip AND songs.zip....the script works perfectly on windows WAMP.

Comment: Ok. I've added a possible solution as an aswer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the file paths you can iterate over all extracted files and move them.

Supposing inside your loop over all extracted files you have a variable `$source` containing the file path (e.g. `username01\filename01.txt`) you can do the following:

```
// Get a string with the correct file path
$target = str_replace('\\', '/', $source);

// Create the directory structure to hold the new file
$dir = dirname($target);
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
}

// Move the file to the correct path.
rename($source, $target);
```

**Edit**

You should check for a backslash in the file name before executing the logic above. With the iterator, your code should look something like this:

```
// Assuming the same directory in your code sample.
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('./uploads');
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (
        $fileinfo->isFile() 
        && strpos($fileinfo->getFilename(), '\\') !== false // Checking for a backslash
    ) {
        $source = $fileinfo->getPathname();

        // Do the magic, A.K.A. paste the code above

    }
}
```

Comment: Still does the same thing. I do not think the mkdir function and rename function did anything. I'd post my code but it wont fit into the comment.

Comment: @Zachary, you can update your question adding the code you've tried.

Comment: Can I get your email address? The code above is more conceptual than the actual code. I'd like to send you the actual code.

Comment: @Zachary, I'm sorry, but we're not allowed to post email addresses here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37956/allow-users-to-put-their-e-mail-in-posts. However, you can see my contacts in my profile. Anyway, I've updated my answer one more time, adding some details about the how to iterate over the extracted files.

Comment: You rock! it works! I'd like to keep in touch as we are constantly needing PHP developers for projects.